# htaccess url rewrite and path reduction

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need help with this issue, i am currently using this htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?show=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?show=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When i open this url:

```
www.domain.com/index.php?show=about
```

it displays this as url:

```
www.domain.com/about
```

I need to be able to display one page which its content changes depending of the variable,
lets say i got

```
www.domain.com/index.php?show=page&title=android
www.domain.com/index.php?show=page&title=ios
```

should display the following url

```
www.domain.com/android
www.domain.com/ios
```

is this possible to do with htaccess?

thanks a lot before hand

Comment: anyone got any idea of how to do what i need?

Answer (score 0):

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?show=page&title=([^\s&]+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]
```

Please put the snippet right before `Header` directive. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks mudasobwa, i added that line right below "RewriteEngine On", and tested it but all it did was go from www.domain.com/index.php?show=page&title=android to www.domain.com/page... i need it to display as www.domain.com/android

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was interrupted in the middle of answering and forgot to write the half.

Comment: sorry still displays as www.domain.com/page

Comment: is it possible to remove the path of the url     www.domain.com/index.php?show=page&title=android to 'www.domain.com/android' ?

Comment: @anonimoo90 Please, excuse my yesterday’s thoughtlessness; it looks like I was a bit tired. Please see update; I have checked it and it works for me.

Comment: I put the snippet right before the Header directive and i am sorry to say that it still displays the url www.domain.com/index.php?show=page&title=android as www.domain.com/page :(

Comment: It looks like it’s a matter of directive precedence. Would you mind to try to move it above your “global” `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?show=([^\s&]+) [NC]` (or even remove the latter in testing purposes?)

Comment: i moved it around and was the same; i removed the   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?show=([^\s&]+) [NC] and all pages would display as www.domain.com/index.php?show=(about|page|etc)

Comment: I’m very sorry, but it looks like I can’t be helpful. It seems there is smth besides the `.htaccess`, since the directives above worked for me.

Comment: aww, dunno what to do now :(, thank you very much for your help though